# Laravel and vuejs -> how to pass Controller data into my Vue view?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5

I am discovering php, laravel, vuejs at the same time and I guess there are some things I didn't get well yet ;)

I made a new component "tableau" which is a basic table and would like to use it at many places in my app, where I would just specify its title, columns and data.
FootballerController is the place where I get all my data.

Here is what is working now:

**app.js**

```
const tableau = new Vue({
    components:{tableau:Tableau
   },
   data: function() {
        return  {
            title: "the best footballers",
            searchQuery: '',
            gridColumns: ['footballer', 'cote', 'nationalite'],
            gridData: [
                { footballer: 'Remond', cote: 951, nationalite:'USA' },
                { footballer: 'Marcel', cote: 935, nationalite:'ESP' },
                { footballer: 'Stian', cote: 923, nationalite:'NOR' },
                { footballer: 'Martin', cote: 923, nationalite:'USA' },
                { footballer: 'Pierre', cote: 918, nationalite:'ESP' },
            ]
        }
   }
}).$mount('#tableau');
```

**footballer.blade.php**

```
<tableau
    v-bind:titre="title"
    :rows="gridData"
    :columns="gridColumns "
    :filter-key="searchQuery" >
  </tableau>
```

**TableauComponent**

```
<template>
    <div >
       <h1 >{{titre}}</h1>
       <table >
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th v-for="key in columns"
                    {{ key | capitalize }}
                </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="entry in rows">
                    <td v-for="key in columns">
                    {{entry[key]}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    name:'tableau',
    props: {
        rows: Array,
        columns: Array,
        titre: String
  }
}
</script>
```

This works.

Then, here is what I would like: being able to put my values from the controller into footballer.blade.php, which is using TableauComponent.vue

**FootballerController**

```
public function footballer($id){
    //process to get all this data in DB ($footballer, $gridData, $gridColumns, $title)
$footballer= (Footballer::select(SOME REQUEST)->where('id', '=', $id)->get())[0];

        return view('footballers/footballer', ['footballer' => $footballer,
        'gridData' => $gridData,
        'gridColumns' =>  $gridColumns,
        'title' => $title] );
    }
```

And in **footballer.blade.php**

```
  <tableau
    v-bind:titre="{{ $title }}"
    :rows="{{ $gridData }}"
    :columns="{{ $gridColumns }}" >
  </tableau>
```

Then in **app.js** I wouldn't need data anymore

```
const tableau = new Vue({
    components:{tableau:Tableau
   }
}).$mount('#tableau');
```

But this doesn't work and tells me "Property or method is not defined on the instance but referenced during render"

I don't manage at all and am worndering is I have the good way of doing: Should I not get my data in FootballerController? If not, where can I get it then?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using? 5.2?

Comment: Can you show the content of `{{ $title }}` by holding `Ctrl + u`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `{{ value }}` in both Blade & javascript framework at the same time. You need to use [`@{{ value }}`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#displaying-data) to avoid collision between Blade & Vue.

try

```
<tableau
  v-bind:titre="@{{ $title }}"
  :rows="@{{ $gridData }}"
  :columns="@{{ $gridColumns }}" >
</tableau>
```

Besides that, when you use `:rows="value"`, the `value` must be javascript syntax, otherwise when `rows="value"`, the `value` would be treated as `string`.

You might need to use `json_encode` to format your data from the Laravel, or use [`@json`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#displaying-data) if you're using Laravel 5.5^.

Answer (score 2):

Your are using ':' symbol before your attributes in your blade, which means 'v-bind' as the doc says : [VueJS Shorthands](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Shorthands).
So first, for assigning a String to a props, you don't need ':' before 'titre'.

Then, to solve your problem you could try to add a default value to your props, for example :

```
props: {
    rows: {
        default: []
    },
    columns: {
        default: []
    },
    titre: {
        default: ''
    }
}
```

I didn't try but I think it should works.

Comment: Thanks a lot Takachi! indeed removing : helps when I have a string. With an array it doesn't work though, even after I changed the props as you suggested: 
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: I think that your rows and columns array contains another array or an object. Laravel provides a good debug tool which is dd(). This method allows you to display array content on your page. Using `dd($rows)` in your controller may help you understanding your variable content and solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, indeed the php array to javascript array was the issue.

In the php controller, I parse my data into json

```
'gridData' =>json_encode($gridData),
```

In the php view footballer.blade.php

```
<tableau
   titre="{{ $title }}"
   rows="{{ $gridData }}">
</tableau>
```

And in my Vue view, I was getting an array, and changed the code for this:

```
 rows: {
          type: String,
          default: ""
      }

 var rowsArray = JSON.parse(this.rows)
```

Now it seems like the data I get after my request isn't properly parsed, but that's another point :)